# How to setup Cloudfront with multiple origin Vue websites to route to correct deep link

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I have defined a Cloudfront distribution (with an example domain of mydomain.com), and setup multiple S3 origins into it.
Each origin is basically a Vue app, and each vue app has its own routing.

Example origins:

```
myrepo1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
myrepo2.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
mybaserepo.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

For example I have defined Behaviors in Cloudfront to have these path patterns:

```
dashboard/* -> myrepo1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
admin/* -> myrepo2.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
Default (*) -> mybaserepo.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

But for myrepo2 the Vue routing has the following child routes:

```
admin/earnings
admin/analytics
admin/projects
```

I have setup that when I navigate to `mydomain.com/admin/` I get redirected correctly to `myrepo2.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` origin.

But, my question is, How can I setup my Cloudfront so that when I navigate to
`mydomain.com/admin/earnings` I get redirected correctly to that route.

I did try to create additional behavior path pattern like

```
admin/earnings -> myrepo2.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

or

```
admin/** -> myrepo2.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```